# Rails App Deploying to Heroku Application Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm migrating my app to Heroku and using a MySQL ClearDB addon. However, upon deploying and attempting to view the app, leads to the page:

[image]

and the log (my apologies for the length):

```
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688899+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688917+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688914+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688915+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688918+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688921+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688923+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-03-17T02:25:14.688924+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-03-17T02:25:15.498865+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-03-17T02:25:16.549374+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-tor-3589.herokuapp.com request_id=4675fd2
5-7ef8-41cb-929b-1edab9d13189 fwd="*************" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-03-17T02:25:15.517544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-03-17T02:25:16.869085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-tor-3589.herokuapp.com request
_id=44755c2f-fbb2-45d2-a2cb-320224891ada fwd="*************" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-03-17T02:26:48+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-03-17T02:27:19.225204+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 01fdec8 by kjakah08@gmail.com
2015-03-17T02:27:19.225204+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v15 created by kjakah08@gmail.com
2015-03-17T02:27:19+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-03-17T02:27:19.596998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-03-17T02:27:24.842389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 4736 -e production`
2015-03-17T02:27:27.872900+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
2015-03-17T02:27:33.560719+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561366+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-4.0.1/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:105:in `validates':
You need to supply at least one validation (ArgumentError)
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561375+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.560727+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561373+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/active_campaign_dow.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.560723+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:4736
2015-03-17T02:27:33.560725+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-03-17T02:27:33.560728+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561377+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block inrequire'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561398+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561380+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561390+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561372+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/active_campaign_dow.rb:6:in `<class:ActiveCampaignDow>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561412+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561381+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561379+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561396+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561386+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561407+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561394+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561387+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561411+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561389+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561410+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561450+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561414+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561391+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561433+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561436+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block inrequire'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561454+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2015-03-17T02:27:33.561385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561418+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561397+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561439+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561404+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561451+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561459+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561403+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561417+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561457+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561449+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561469+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561458+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561465+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561442+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561445+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `blockin <main>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561462+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-03-17T02:27:33.561466+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-03-17T02:27:34.456959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

From the log, there are no explicit errors aside from showing the app crashed error page. I configured everything correctly.

Why won't the  app show?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is rellevant

```
[....]/active_model/validations/validates.rb:105:in `validates':
You need to supply at least one validation (ArgumentError)
```

From the backtrace it seems like you have source of the problem in `app/models/active_campaign_dow.rb:6`, probably mailformed `validates` call

Comment: I have no model called `active_campaign_dow.rb`